# How to manually initialise an array in Solidity?

Tags: arrays, constructor

I can't find a way to manually initialize an array.

```
string[] public cool;

function constructor() {
    cool[0] = "one";
}
```

Won't execute, while

```
function constructor(){
    cool[cool.length++] = "one";
}
```

will.

What might be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't assign a value to an array of size 0, you need to have enough space to write your value. It is true, you declared a *variable size* array but you still need to tell the VM to increase the array size before assign it.

You can increase array size and assign values in different ways:

1. All-in-one (increase and set, my preferred) using **push** method, like this:

   ```
   cool.push("one");
   ```
2. With two commands, setting **length** property and then setting the value

   ```
   cool.length = 1;
   cool[0] = "one";
   ```

Without really knowing it, you **actually** used the second way and you initialized manually the array length. In fact, using `cool.length++` you increased to 1 the array size and, just after that, you passed 0 as key to the array (and note you passed 0 and not 1 because you used ++ after and not before the length variable). All this let you assign correctly "one" string inside the first position of the array.

Aside that, two suggestions:

- Look at **mapping** if you don't want to mess to much with array
  sizes. You can do thing like that:

  ```
  mapping (int=>string) public cool;
  function testMapping() {
      cool[3] = "hello";
      cool[33] = "world";
      cool[333] = "!!";
  }
  ```

without worrying about sizes.

- Don't use *constructor* as method name, it can be really misleading. If you really need a contract constructor, it must be named as the contract name. If you need an init function, name it init().

Comment: Note: The advice at the end about constructor classes is not correct as of Solidity 0.4.22+. "constructor()" now *is* the correct nomenclature. Check the documentation for the latest version: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#constructor