# Simple call exceeding block gas limit

Tags: gas, out-of-gas

I'm using Remix to deploy onto Rinkeby.

I can deploy the contract fine, although I have to increase the 3000000 gas limit to 13000000.

When I trigger an event that updates a `uint256` field, the transaction goes through fine.

However, when I change that to update a single array value `myArray[0] = someint`, it gives me `callback contain no result Gas required exceeds block gas limit: 13000000`, and doesn't matter what I set gas limit to.

Specifically:

```
address[] public addressList;
uint public someint;

function testit() payable {
  addressList[0] = msg.sender;   // This line always exceeds gas limit

  someint = msg.value;  // Only this line works

  sendFunds(); // does this: ownerwallet.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Why would such a trivial call exceed the gas limit?

Comment: The production chain has a gas limit of about 6.7 Megagas. If deploying your contract really takes 13 Megagas, you won't be able to deploy it to production. Beyond that, @benjaminion's answer looks appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this Q&A](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/how-to-manually-initialise-an-array-in-solidity) answers your question as well.

It's not about gas - using up all the gas is just a side-effect of a failure in your code (this is what currently happens on an exception in Ethereum).

Essentially, you are trying to make an assignment to a zero-length array.

You need to do either `addressList.push(msg.sender)`, or you need to declare the array statically, `address[10] public addressList`.  There is more info at the answer I linked.