# VM Exception: Contract from within a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, dapp-development, testrpc

I am following this [example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/solidity-create-contract-from-contract) to experiment with **contract from within a contract** (using testrpc).

```
contract Product {
    bytes32 public Name;

    function Product (bytes32 _Name) {
        Name = _Name;
    }
}

contract ProductFactory {

    bytes32[] public productNames;
    address[] public productAddresses;

    function addProduct (bytes32 _productName) {
        address newProduct = new Product(_productName);
        productAddresses.push(newProduct);
    }

    function getName (uint i) {
    Product prod = Product(productAddresses[i]);

    productNames[i] = prod.Name();
  }
}
```

My filename is Product.sol and the deloy file in truffle is:

```
var Product = artifacts.require("./Product.sol");
var ProductFactory = artifacts.require('ProductFactory');


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // deployer.deploy(supplyChain);
  deployer.deploy(Product);
  deployer.deploy(ProductFactory);
};
```

On deploy, ProductFactory and Product both work well, as demonstrated by creating a new product with addProduct. However, on doing a getName, error: VM Exception is returned.

```
truffle(development)> ProductFactory.deployed().then(function(instance){PF=ProductFactory.at(instance.address)})

truffle(development)> PF.addProduct('abcd')
{ tx: '0xe304f9194fb9b06ae5f0a3664f64255e74d88de099cce0cd38092030b5d48d7f',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0xe304f9194fb9b06ae5f0a3664f64255e74d88de099cce0cd38092030b5d48d7f',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x09d3e5547b1d4cd9ef40d05b5b15561a45b9f62f55410d03c175886dd1c591eb',
     blockNumber: 122,
     gasUsed: 122275,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 122275,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }

truffle(development)> PF.getName(0)
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37047:16)
...
```

**EDIT1:**
When I am trying the following,

```
truffle(development)> PF.productAddresses(0)
'0x4b01bd4691c306c59e8985bb6bd5bcc88abf1e81'
truffle(development)> Product.at('0x4b01bd4691c306c59e8985bb6bd5bcc88abf1e81').Name()
'0x6162686900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

understandably it works. `PF.productAddresses(0)` is an ***object*** as I gathered, and when I am using `Product.at(PF.productAddresses(0))` it fails the same way as `getName`. However, on directly using the address ***string*** as just shown, it works. How to manage this issue?

**EDIT1 over:**

I am a newbie. If someone could let me know what might I am doing wrong. I think it is to do with async call, but I am not sure. I have tried multiple variations and on Remix as well, but it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is about having multiple contracts, you have an issue in the `getName()` function with this statement:

```
    productNames[i] = prod.Name();
```

You are not allowed to assign to an index beyond the end of a dynamically sized array. More specifically, when you first call `getName()`, the `productNames` array has zero size, so you can't assign to one of its elements: there aren't any.

You'd be better using `productNames.push(_productName)` within your `addProduct()` function and removing `getName()` entirely.

Alternatively, you could use a mapping instead of an array with `i` as your key.  That is, change your declaration of `productNames` as follows; the rest of the code is unchanged:

```
mapping (uint => bytes32) productNames;
```

This works, but it's a weird way to code it (imho).

See also [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/how-to-manually-initialise-an-array-in-solidity) Q&A.

Comment: Perfect, rather than removing getName altogether, I tried increasing array size by 1 (in addName) and checking whether it works - as you gave the reference for wherein there are two ways to increase array size, push, or increasing length. 
Both approach work! The mapping idea is interesting, must say, though I will go ahead with conventional ones. Thanks again!